# Стоит ли хранить файлы в базе данных?

Tags: php, mysql

На PHPclab прочитал, что в MySQL базе данных можно хранить файлы.
У меня сайт небольшой. Стоит ли хранить файлы в базе данных?
Каковы плюсы и минусы хранения файлов в БД?

Comment: Как это файлы? может адреса файлов, да?

Comment: хм, а размер файлов какой, в каких пределах? )

Comment: http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/upload#part_1 Именно файлы, а не адреса. от нескольких Кб до 4 Гб вроде. На других сайтах тоже инфа такая есть.

Comment: пару КБ можно хранить, но от МБ уже слишком

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно и файлы. Можно. Но зачем? На каждый чих лазать в БД и извлекать оттуда файлы? А тем более если это какие-нибудь картинки для оформления сайта - загнется все очень скоро. Один раз я наблюдал механизм загрузки файлов на сайт и последующее хранение их в сериализованном виде в  MSSQL, и единственный плюс, который тут виден - файл не выполнить на сервере. В остальном - дрянной способ хранения статики.
Из подобного вопроса на stackoverflow: ""You want to return 4GB from a dynamic web request? You're doing something wrong."

Comment: Значит такой вариант отметаю. Просто интересно стало.